# SQL Server - Join with simple condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple JOIN question

**Condition:**

- Set A has a fix number of elements (say 10 elements) and never change
  (always has 10 elements).
- Set B is a subset of set A and can either has zero elements (empty set) or some elements (from 1 to 10).

Is it possible to write a JOIN query (without using IF ... ELSE... or CASE... WHEN) to return result so that:

- If Set B is empty, return all elements from set A.
- If Set B is not empty, return only elements from set B.

---

### **Giorgos Betsos has solved this problem!!!!!!!!!**

### I've posted my example as below.

```
CREATE TABLE #A (number INT PRIMARY KEY) 
INSERT INTO #A(number) VALUES(0)
INSERT INTO #A(number) VALUES(1)
INSERT INTO #A(number) VALUES(2)
INSERT INTO #A(number) VALUES(3)
INSERT INTO #A(number) VALUES(4)
INSERT INTO #A(number) VALUES(5)
INSERT INTO #A(number) VALUES(6)
INSERT INTO #A(number) VALUES(7)
INSERT INTO #A(number) VALUES(8)
INSERT INTO #A(number) VALUES(9)

CREATE TABLE #B (number INT PRIMARY KEY)

SELECT *
FROM #A
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT number FROM #B)

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM #B

DROP TABLE #A
DROP TABLE #B
```

Comment: have you tried to solve this "simple join" problem yet?

Comment: Without Sample data, DDL, and expoected results, only answers you're going to get are guesses. But, as a guess, use a `LEFT JOIN` and perhaps `ISNULL`?

Comment: I think some sample data and desired results would be 100x more understandable then explaining the set with words here.

Comment: That being said. `SELECT coalesce(setb.f1, seta.f1) as f1, coalesce(setb.f2, seta.f2) as f2 FROM seta LEFT OUTER JOIN setb on seta.f1=setb.f1` is probably the pattern you are looking for. That's a bit of a guess though since it's not super clear from your explaination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way of getting the result you want is:

```
SELECT *
FROM A
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM B)

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM B
```

If `B` is empty the query returns all `A` records (from the fist query of the `UNION` operation).

If `B` is not empty then just the records of this table are returned (from the second query of the `UNION` operation).

Comment: Perhaps `UNION ALL` instead?

Comment: Thank you Giorgos. Your query works. I'll post an example in my question.

Comment: @jarlh Yes `UNION ALL` is more suitable here.